# How to run a SQL command from a bash variable via ssh and psql?

Tags: sql, bash, ssh, escaping, psql

I do want to run a SQL command which is stores in a bash variable via `ssh postgres@hostname psql dbname -c SQL_COMMAND`.

Considering that the SQL command has strings in it, what is the proper way of running this, so it is properly escaped?

Example: `SQL_COMMAND="SELECT 'aaa'"`

I am looking for a solution that takes care of the escaping, so I can easily run other SQL commands without having to escape them myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite awkward to do in the shell. Given the choice I'd use a scripting language that was less sensitive about metacharacters. The shell is just painful. The only way I'm aware of to get reliable raw strings is with either (a) an input function like `read`; (b) a temporary file; or (c) with a quoted here-document.

Here's what I'd do, exploiting the way `ssh` passes stdin through:

```
$ ssh hostname psql <<"__END__"
SELECT 'aaa!*#${notavar}' FROM "generate_series"(1,2);
__END__

     ?column?     
------------------
 aaa!*#${notavar}
 aaa!*#${notavar}
(2 rows)
```

Unfortunately you can't easily wrap that in `$( ... )` to store it in a shell variable. It'll seem to work, but certain meta-characters like `!` will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me by just doing `psql -c "$SQLCOMMAND"`

```
% export SQLCOMMAND='select "generate_series"(1, 5, 1);'
% echo $SQLCOMMAND
select "generate_series"(1, 5, 1);
% psql -c "$SQLCOMMAND"
 generate_series 
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
(5 rows)
```

or

```
% export SQLCOMMAND="SELECT 'aaa' FROM \"generate_series\"(1,2);"
% echo $SQLCOMMAND
SELECT 'aaa' FROM "generate_series"(1,2);
% psql -c "$SQLCOMMAND"
 ?column? 
----------
 aaa
 aaa
(2 rows)
```

Provided you can get the SQL statement into the variable correctly, double quoting the argument to `psql`'s `-c` option seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, but that'll fall apart with "double quoted" identifiers.

Comment: SELECT 'aaa' FROM "generate_series"(1,2);

Comment: Yes, as edited... but the OP appears to want a way to do it *without* having to escape SQL manually. *"I am looking for a solution that takes care of the escaping, so I can easily run other SQL commands without having to escape them myself."*

Comment: I'm only escaping to get the SQL statement correctly into the environment variable. Once there, it's passed as is. Semantics. I'll leave it up to the OP to decide whether or not this is useful.

Comment: Fair enough. You'll need to double the escaping to pass it through `ssh` to `psql -c` then. `ssh localhost /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql -c "$SQLCOMMAND"` will fail with `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. You'd need to use something like bash's `printf '%q'`